# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

[image]

How to remove warning?

Comment: Basically, you need to remove those `java` command line options from wherever they are coming from.  It is hard to tell from the screenshot what you are actually doing here.  It looks like you are launching a spring app from within IntelliJ.  So try checking the Intellij launcher (actuator?) config for those deprecated options and then remove them.

Comment: Also ... [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

The -noverify option is included if you select (by default it is selected) "Enable launch optimization" under Springboot section. Disable it in your launcher would make this warning disappear.

[image]

However, it's just the warning, i think it wouldn't cause any harm to your application :).

Comment: note:  for disable "Enable launch optimization" checkbox,
you can find this window in path :
Top of intelij Idea
 `Run->Edit Configurations...`